# Selecting the Max and Min records in one MySQL command

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to select two records from a table based on ID.

I need the first one, and the last one (so min, and max)

Example:

```
Customer
        ID   NAME
        1     Bob
        50    Bob
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The art of looking at manuals is lost: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM tabla
```

**EDIT:** If you need to retrive the values of the row you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLA AS a, (SELECT MIN(id) AS mini,
                            MAX(id) AS maxi
                     FROM   TABLA) AS m
WHERE  m.maxi = a.id
       OR m.mini = a.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select id, name from customers where id = ( select max(id) from customers )
union all
select id, name from customers where id = ( select min(id) from customers )
```

Now I have tested this type of query on a MySQL database I have access, and it works. My query:

```
SELECT nome, livello
FROM personaggi
WHERE livello = (
SELECT max( livello )
FROM personaggi )
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `group by`, my bad.

Comment: still not working "Error: 1111 Invalid use of group function"

Comment: Aww, I was guessing since I hadn't access to a MySQL instance. :\ Now I have and I tested it, and it's working (at least the second script I posted).

Answer (score 2):

If ties for first and/or last place are not a concern, then consider the following query:

```
(SELECT id, name FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, name FROM customers ORDER BY id LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
    select * from customer where id in ((select min(id) from customer),(select max(id) 
from customer));
```

Answer (score -4):

SELECT MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM table