# Choose the Minimum Value in Query

Tags: mysql

I have viewed many Q&A's regarding selecting MIN value from column names i.e
[find min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254567/selecting-the-max-and-min-records-in-one-mysql-command)
but my problem is not solved.

```
SELECT MIN(column1  + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60) AS deadline1, column2 +(1 * 24 * 60 * 60) AS deadline2) AS deadline FROM table_name
```

Showing error code `Error Code : 1064`

How can I select the minimum value from both values? any idea plz?

Comment: You shouldn't have `AS` clause inside a function call

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368351/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-minimum-value-from-multiple-columns

Comment: @ChetterHummin That's SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar True, but MySQL has a case structure as well which can be used. A good reference is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: @ChetterHummin: actually I was using the wrong function here, its solution was to use the least function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL uses `MIN` only as an aggregate function. To select the minimum of several expressions, you have to use `LEAST`:

```
SELECT LEAST(column1  + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60), column2 +(1 * 24 * 60 * 60)) AS deadline FROM table_name
```